# java ee7 jdbc realm security configuration problems

Tags: java, mysql, security, jdbc, jdbcrealm

First, i've read numerous threads on stackoverflow regarding the same issue, the javaee7tutorial, javaee6tutorial... In reality, i'm doing more reading on stackoverflow than on the official documentation - utterly ridiculous considering that i've literally eaten those two books.

Here it goes:

rest-application, must use jdbc security realm with mysql backend. Minimal complexity - no foreign keys, not data integrity, just make it work.

### MySQL config:

```
create table users (
user varchar(20),
pass varchar(300)
);
```

---

```
create table groups (
user varchar(20),
gr varchar(20)
);
```

---

```
create trigger tt 
before insert on users
for each row 
set new.pass=sha2(new.pass, 256);
```

---

```
insert into users(user, pass) values('bob', 'secret');
```

---

```
insert into groups(user, gr) values('bob', 'user');
```

---

```
web.xml config:
```

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>test</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/webapi/serv/search/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>actor</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <realm-name>dbtest</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

glassfish-web.xml config:

```
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>actor</role-name>
    <group-name>user</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```

glassfish 4 -> admin console -> security -> domain config:

```
realm name: dbtest
class name: com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm
jaas context: dbtest
jndi: mysql //this is the resource name, uses the same resource the app itself
user table: jdbcusers.users //jdbcusers is the name of the database, fully qualified name
user name column: user
password column: pass
group table: jdbcusers.groups //again, fully qualified name
group name column: gr
password encryption algorithm: SHA-256
encoding: Hex
```

all other field are empty.

Needless to say, if i use the file domain, i can login successfully, everything works as expected. The connection to the db is sure to work, because i use the same resource the app is using to query search results. The mysql user has permissions to select statements on those tables - i've confirmed it.

What can i be doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't said what's going wrong.